# Mathematica analog to Wolfram|Alpha dataset analysis

Tags: integer-sequence

I have a set of sequences with length 8,48,480,5760,.. and would like to do sequence analysis on them.  I plugged the length 8 sequence into wolframalpha:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=11,+2,+1,+8,+7,+14,+13,+4

This gives the output:

Diophantine relations: 11 - 2 - 1 + 8 + 7 - 14 - 13 + 4 = 0 11 - 2 + 1 - 8 - 7 + 14 - 13 + 4 = 0 11 + 2 - 1 - 8 - 7 - 14 + 13 + 4 = 0 11^2 + 2^2 - 1^2 - 8^2 - 7^2 - 14^2 + 13^2 + 4^2 = 0 11^3 + 2^3 - 1^3 - 8^3 - 7^3 - 14^3 + 13^3 + 4^3 = 0

I exceeded the free computation time for any more processing of the larger sequences, is there a way to do the same as Wolfram|Alpha does?  I can send the longer sequences if someone is able to plug them into Wolfram|Alpha Pro.  Thanks.

cheers,
Jamie

Comment: The sequence lengths sequence is [OEIS sequence 5867](https://oeis.org/A005867) and this not a coincidence. Even for length 48 there are too many possibilities for naive search to check in any reasonable time. I know that the sign patterns found have a number theoretic origin.

Comment: Hi, there is a draft for the sequence here: https://oeis.org/draft/A308121.  These 48,480,5760 length sequences are on Primorial rows, ie rows 210,2310,30030.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) for this purpose. Let `v` be your vector:

```
v = {11, 2, 1, 8, 7, 14, 13, 4};
```

Then, to find the linear Diophantine relations:

```
linear = Solve[
    v . a == 0 && 
    a ∈ RegionProduct @@ Prepend[
        Table[Point[{{-1},{1}}],7],
        Point[{{1}}]
    ],
    a
]
```

> {{a -> {1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1}}, {a -> {1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
>       1}}, {a -> {1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1}}}

Comparison:

```
v #& /@ (a /. linear)
```

> {{11, -2, -1, 8, 7, -14, -13, 4}, {11, -2, 1, -8, -7, 14, -13, 4}, {11, 
>     2, -1, -8, -7, -14, 13, 4}}

To find the quadratic Diophantine relations:

```
Solve[
    vec^2 . a == 0 && 
    a ∈ RegionProduct @@ Prepend[
        Table[Point[{{-1},{1}}],7],
        Point[{{1}}]
    ],
    a
]
```

> {{a -> {1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1}}}

etc.

Comment: Would you be able to analyze this sequence?  27, -18, 1, 4, 23, 26, 13, 32, 19, 22, 41, 44, 31, 18, 37, 24, 27, 46, 33, 36, 23, -6, -3, 16, 19, 38, 41, 12, -1, 2, -11, 8, 11, -2, 17, 4, -9, -6, 13, 16, 3, 22, 9, 12, 31, 34, 53, 8

Answer (score 1):

Another approach using [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

diophantine[p_Integer?Positive] :=
 Inner[Times, coef,
    If[p == 1, seq, Inactive[Power][#, p] & /@ seq],
    Inactive[Plus]] == 0 /.
  Union[
   Solve[
    seq^p.coef == 0 && And @@ (# == -1 || # == 1 & /@ coef),
    coef],
   SameTest -> ((coef /. #1) == -(coef /. #2) &)]

seq = {11, 2, 1, 8, 7, 14, 13, 4};

coef = Array[c, Length@seq];

Column[d[1] = diophantine[1]]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
And @@ (d[1] // Activate)

(* True *)

Column[d[2] = diophantine[2]]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
And @@ (d[2] // Activate)

(* True *)

Column[d[3] = diophantine[3]]
```

[image]

Verifying,

```
And @@ (d[3] // Activate)

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to reduce the memory requirements?  I tried it on seq={27, -18, 1, 4, 23, 26, 13, 32, 19, 22, 41, 44, 31, 18, 37, 24, 27, 46, 33, 36, 23, -6, -3, 16, 19, 38, 41, 12, -1, 2, -11, 8, 11, -2, 17, 4, -9, -6, 13, 16, 3, 22, 9, 12, 31, 34, 53, 8}  But Mathematica exited after using 16GB ram.